# bash process substitution hangs for script output

Tags: bash

this works:

```
sort <(seq 10)
```

but this does not work

```
sort <(seq.sh 10)
```

where seq.sh looks like

```
#/bin/bash
seq $1
```

How I can make seq.sh work for this?

--  edit --
sorry for typo.
`seq.sh` is excutable and has correct shabang line.

I guess it is related with EOF something.
This works as well with trailing `&`

```
sort <(./seq.sh 10 &)
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Is `seq.sh` executable?

Comment: "does not work" means "hangs". thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use `seq.sh` as a path, for example `./seq.sh` or its absolute path.  Remember to make it executable.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the ! to the shebang.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Also I would make sure that the shell script is executable.

```
chmod +x seq.sh
```

lastly, pipe into sort: (the example has an input of 10)

```
./seq.sh 10 | sort
```

This was my output:

```
user@MBP:~/Desktop$ ./seq.sh 10 | sort
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```